# Copying projects in eclipse, what do I change to allow both versions on the same device?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I've copied and pasted an app project inside eclipse, but need to be able to install both 'versions' at once on my device. What do I need to do in the manifest to allow this?

All I can find through searching is people saying this needs to be done, e.g.

> if you fork an app also don't forget to change android:authorities(and the ContentProvider AUTHORITY) or it won't install on the same device with the original app

But I can't find any specific instructions. The default for android:authorities is to leave it out, and I'm not sure how to set it manually. The apps are being used for academic purposes and don't need to go beyond my own tablet; can anyone point me towards some resources or provide some instructions to deal with the authorities issue so I can have both installed at once?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you only need to change the package name.

`android:authority` is present in very few apps, and even in the ones it is present, you just need to change the package name part. The rest of it remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change the package name in the manifest file.  That is the identity of the application as far as Android is concerned.

Comment: Of course this will trigger other changes too.  For example any element name in the manifest that starts with a dot will be in the new package rather than the old one (which means you have to actually move it there or else fully qualify the name in themanifest.)    Also the generated resource class, R, will be in the new package which means you may need to change imports in your program. It would probably be simplest to change that package name by refactor/name in the project explorer.